# Argument to a function only if variable is not None

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to add headers or data as arguments to `request.post()` only if headers or data is available. What is the cleanest pythonic way of doing this?

```
def req( url, headers=None, data=None): 
    if "form-urlencoded" in headers["Content-Type"]:
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
    return requests.post(
        url,
        headers = headers,
        data = data,
    )
```

Comment: Can you use `requests.post` directly?

Comment: No, It's a layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `data` is `None` (https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post). So why change it? It sounds like all you need to do is a simple passthrough like you are doing.

For the `headers` as @Qharr pointed out you can use the [default headers](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/5855dd7/requests/utils.py#L817-L826) of the `requests` package as a default if you like.

However, you should null check `headers` before you attempt to access a value by key:

```py
def req( url, headers=None, data=None): 
    if headers is not None and data is not None and "form-urlencoded" in headers["Content-Type"]:
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
    return requests.post(
        url,
        headers = headers,
        data = data,
    )
```

Comment: Okay. It does say that the default for body is None but where does it say that for headers? Also what if the function I wanted to use did not use None as its default?

Comment: You're right there - but what happens when you set headers to `None`? Does it work? If it doesn't then you can coerce headers to `{}` or whatever it needs to be.

I don't think you have to change anything if your function defaults change.

Comment: I'm not sure you are correct about stating default headers are None. https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L805

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use **kwargs in the function signature instead of specifying headers and data and then pass these kwargs to the post method